# how to make layers not overlap with each other in css

Tags: html, css

I have a problem here with my website. If you can go to [my website](http://xestudio.xco.kr) and click on the cog button on the left side, there are two images.

If you click on the first image, i set it to change `.xe-clearfix` css style to `background-color:white`, and for the 2nd image, i set it to change `.xe-clearfix` css style to `background-color:transparent` as well.

but as you can see, the menu and the image slider overlap with each other,
so basically what im trying to achieve here is to make the menu on the top of the slider 'push' the slider down, so that none is overlapping when i click on the first image.

(and remove that class when click on the 2nd image of course)

and since I can't copy paste the whole website here, i will simply leave my website's address.

and bare in mind that I use wordpress like CMS called XE,
and the source code might be 'mess' to some people.

but people often say that my webhosting company (cafe24) gets blocked by the ublock or adblock, I assure you that the website is completely safe and there is no harm whatsoever (you will need to disable your chrome's extension for that matter)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: why not make your .xe-clearfix position relative instead of absolute on the first button press? This will push the slider down...

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The others are right that your question is off-topic without a code snippet, but I'll throw some info up since you're new.

Your header/menu element (`.header_wrap xe-clearfix menu_type_1`) is positioned absolutely. That means it has no affect on other elements on the page.

The element containing the slider (`.camera_wrap camera_white_skin`) would need to be pushed down the height of the header (about 100px) using margin or other styling. This will not be a dynamic solution as it would need to be recalculated if the header height changes.

Bottom line: This layout would need substantial revision to do what you describe. It might be better to start with a different template that has a fixed, separate header bar.